# How can I control my user's Input

Tags: python, user-input

```
 name = input('Enter your name please: ')
 while name != str:
     name = input('Please enter only letters for your name: ')
 ss = input('Enter your Social Security Number: ')
 while ss != int:
     ss = input('Please enter only numbers for your social security number:')
```

So I have this basic program that asks the user for his name and SS# and I wanted to do so the user can't input a str or a float where he is supposed to input an int. I tried this but it'll just loop forever because the If statement is checking to see if the input is the data type str or int, How can I do it to check if the variable is an int or a str?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to compare the value with a `type`. You should instead store the name and check if has only letters (`.isalpha()`) and try a type casting on the security number. If it fails, it's not a valid input. Using `isnumeric()` for the SSN is also an option. Something like:

```
name = input('Enter your name please: ')
while not name.isalpha():
    name = input('Please enter only letters for your name: ')

ss = input('Enter your Social Security Number: ')
try:
    int(ss)
    valid_ss = True
except ValueError:
    valid_ss = False

while not valid_ss:
    ss = input('Please enter only numbers for your social security number:')
    try:
        int(ss)
        valid_ss = True
    except ValueError:
        valid_ss = False
```

or

```
name = input('Enter your name please: ')
while not name.isalpha():
    name = input('Please enter only letters for your name: ')

ss = input('Enter your Social Security Number: ')
while not ss.isnumeric():
    ss = input('Please enter only numbers for your social security number:')
```

Answer (score 2):

`name != str` does not do what you think it does. The result of input() is always a string. If you only want to get certain types of strings, then you have to validate them yourself. For checking if something only contains letters or only contains numbers you can use [`name.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) and [`name.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric).

If you need something more complicated than what these or othe other builtin string methods provide, then you'll probably need to write a regular expression or other custom validation code.